# String to Object Mapping in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Is there a utility method in typescript to map the string to the Object class itself,

```
MapperFunction()

const rawString = "id=a666b09c-680b-44a1-8d26-c25b5cfa0b89, name=Rule 007, active=true, data={codes=[AA, BB, CC, DD]}"        

export interface MyState {
    id: string;
    name: string
    active: string;
    group: string;
    data: InnerClass
}

export interface InnerClass {
   codes: string[];       
}
```

**What I want to do that**

```
const ms:MyState = MapperFunction(rawString, MyState);
```

Comment: Where you use `InnerClass `  in your code?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The short answer is "no". TypeScript is not something magic, it only adds types to JavaScript but the types vanish at compilation, when the compiler produces JavaScript from the TypeScript code. The processing you need happens at runtime. You need to write the function `MapperFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

Create `MapperFunction()` that can get your `string and obj` param. and return as an object. also, you can pass `Mystate` instead of the object based on your `export interface Mystate`.

**Here is a code:**

```
const rawString = "id=a666b09c-680b-44a1-8d26-c25b5cfa0b89, name=Rule 007, active=true, data={codes=[AA, BB, CC, DD]}";

function MapperFunction(rawString: string, obj: any): any {
  const keyValuePairs = rawString.split(", ");
  const result = {};
  for (const pair of keyValuePairs) {
    const [key, value] = pair.split("=");
    result[key] = value;
  }
  const mappedObject = Object.assign({}, obj, result);
  return mappedObject;
}

interface MyState {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  active: string;
  group: string;
}

const ms: MyState = MapperFunction(rawString, {
  id: "",
  name: "",
  active: "",
  group: "",
});

console.log(ms);
```

**Output is:**

```
{
  id: "a666b09c-680b-44a1-8d26-c25b5cfa0b89",
  name: "Rule 007",
  active: "true",
  group: ""
}
```

Comment: updated Class definition, by adding InnerClass, Does your solution work for it as well?

Comment: try with it and update your code as per the answer and see its working or not.

Comment: It does not work since array elements separated by comma

Comment: When you ask a question here, share your whole code what is the issue, and what you want as output. after getting one solution you share another problem, its not a good practice